# displaying data properly with a PHP function

Tags: php

```
public function Read($Table, $Fields, $Condition, $Orderby, $Limit) {
    $Query = "SELECT $Fields FROM $Table";
    if ($Condition != null) {
        $Query .= " WHERE " . $Condition;
    }
    if ($Orderby != null) {
        $Query .= " ORDER BY " . $Orderby;
    }
    if ($Limit != null) {
        $Query .= " LIMIT " . $Limit;
    }
    $Result = mysql_query($Query);
    while ($Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($Result)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($Row as $Key => $Value) {
            echo "<td>" . $Value . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
```

Hello Friends, My goal was to create a generic function as to fetch records from database and display in a table so that i can use it in every application. I've so far managed to show the records in table with the above code. But i want to have a update and delete link on every row in a .. On the update and delete link i want to pass the get value of id for that currect record.

I am also needing some feedback if this is the correct method i am following to make a Read(); function with the aim of making it generic. PS. I just started OOP.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: put your opening and closing tr tag outside of while loop...and you do not need to add foreach inside while.

Comment: i made id intentionally as i want the table to be create dynamically . If i din't use foreach loop i would have to assign $row['id'] , $row['username'] etc...

Comment: @DipeshParmar Both your comments are wrong.

Comment: I suggest you use a plugin like Datatables or jQgrid.

Comment: @Barmar Plugin or thrid party grid is not a solution.. I am currently a student of php and i need to learn rather than copy and pasting things... Its actuall i am making my first php CRUD class

Comment: I would put the `id` of the record as an attribute into the `<tr>` tag so it can easily be picked up by JavaScript (clientside, preferably jQuery) to turn that into buttons for an update or delete.

Comment: @cars10 can you tell me how to extract the id from $key ?

Comment: @RameezShah Just as Barmar has just demonstrated: `$Row[id]` - but, of course this necessitates that `id` is actually one of the columns in your `$Fields` variable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add cells the the table with update and delete links.

```
    while ($Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($Result)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($Row as $Key => $Value) {
            echo "<td>" . $Value . "</td>";
        }
        echo "<td><a href='update.php?id=" . $Row['id'] . "'>Update</a><td>";
        echo "<td><a href='delete.php?id=" . $Row['id'] . "'>Delete</a><td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
```

`update.php` should display a form to update the record, while `delete.php` would just delete the specified record and redirect back to the display page.

Comment: Barmar, This is working fine for me thank you... But i am getting the below error
Notice: Use of undefined constant id - assumed 'id' in E:\Xamp\htdocs\CrudOOP\inc.users.php on line 71

Comment: Sorry, I started by writing it with interplated variables, then changed to concatenation, and forgot to add back the quotes.

Comment: Thanks working perfect !